# mysql select highest and lowest values with limit in one statement

Tags: mysql

I need to pull the 5 highest prices and 5 lowest prices from a table products on column prices.  I thought I could do two select in one stmt like below, but I think you cannot because it is the same table?  I have done similar stmts and it worked but with different tables.

```
SELECT products.* AS fullcount, (SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 5) AS highest, (SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 5) AS lowest FROM products
```

What am I doing wrong or should I be using a different approach?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong".  `SELECT` can only have scalar value.  You are trying to jam 5 rows into your `SELECT`.  How do you think it's possible???

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to combine the results of queries that get the highest and lowest rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM products
    ORDER BY price DESC
    LIMIT 5) x
UNION (
    SELECT *
    FROM products
    ORDER BY price ASC
    LIMIT 5
) y
```

Comment: I remember - we've already been there.. "To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT" :-)

Comment: thanks.  This was still giving me an error
However it looks like it was missing alias for the select sub-query.  I have added AS highest and it looks to be giving me what I'm looking for.

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 5) AS highest UNION ( SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 5 )

Comment: @gstlouis - You don't need that subquery (as derived table). See the second example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)